# is it posible to add cursor on drawtext on canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, drawtext

my code is here

```
textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
canvas.drawText(substring, textX, y, this.textPaint);
```

I want to add here also cursor like edittext

Comment: why don't you use styled `EditText`?

Comment: @DimaRostopira because I want to add text on clicked position and I have to use canvas for another drawing element  together  can works

Answer (score 4):

You can draw blinking cursor this way:

```
private long lastCursorChangeState = -1;
private boolean cursorVisible = true;
private Rect textBounds = new Rect();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
    if(isWriting){
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCursorChangeState > 500) {
            cursorVisible = !cursorVisible;
            lastCursorChangeState = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        if(cursorVisible){
            paint.getTextBounds(textToDraw, 0, textToDraw.length(), textBounds);
            canvas.drawLine(textX+textBounds.right, textY-textSize, textX+textBounds.right, textY, paint);
        }

        postInvalidateDelayed(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as i know it's not possible, because the text is part of a bitmap and not interpreted as text by the textmarker interface.

I would suggest another solution:

1. Use a encapsulated layout-structure like that (layout only simplyfied!)

   ```
   <FrameLayout>
        <Canvas />
        <TextView />
        <!-- More textviews -->
   </FrameLayout>
   ```
2. You can position the textview inside the framelayout by calling the function **setX** or **setY**. The textview will then always be drawn on top of the canvas, as long as the textview is defined after the canvas. Furthermore you can make it visible/invisible by code by calling the function **setVisibility**
3. In addition to that, you can add more Textviews to the framelayout dynamically using code instead of defining the textview statically in the layout xml